# Get Aggregate Data In MongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

[image]

Here is the mongo DB document structure provided above in the image. There you can see we have got a **xmlRequests array under pages array** (Pages is array of objects). So each session has pages array containing some objects

**What I want to do:**

Let us say we have 10 documents with same structure as shown in the image above. I want the aggregate (unified) array of all the **pages** under all the sessions in one array. In simple words I want the pages array of all the sessions in one array. **(Aggregate)**

**Like this:**

```
{
 pages : [] // array containing all the objects of request arrays under each session.
}
```

I need a one unified **requests[ ]** array containing all the requests of all the sessions in one single array. I tried using **db.collection.aggregate([ ])** but I don't know how to get the nested values in a document and unify all of them in one single array of objects.

Mongo Code Snippet

```
{
 "user": "abc",
 "sessions": {
 "12345": {
    "pages": [
        {
            requests: [ {name: 'request1'}]
        }
    ]
    },
  "23456": {
    "pages": [
        {
            requests: [ {name: 'request1'}]
        }
    ]
    }
    }
}

{
  "user": "xyz",
  "sessions": {
  "12345": {
    "pages": [
        {
            requests: [ {name: 'request1'}]
        }
    ]
    },
   "23456": {
    "pages": [
        {
            requests: [ {name: 'request1'}]
        }
    ]
     }
    }
   }
```

**FETCH ALL REQUEST ARRAYS IN THE COLLECTION AND COMBINE THEM INTO ONE ARRAY**

Comment: Can you paste your sample data as code instead of an image? Thanks!

Comment: @mickl Can you please check i have added.

Comment: Do you want all sessions per user or all just one document which contains all users sessions?

Comment: @mickl One document which contains all the requests that are under pages of all session id's.
Not the sessions but the requests that are in pages array of each session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) in order to retrieve values from unknown keys. Then you need a couple of [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) / [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) pairs to flatten arrays of arrays. [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) can be used to collect all requests into a single document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            pages: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$sessions" },
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                $reduce: {
                                    input: "$$this.v.pages",
                                    initialValue: [],
                                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this.requests" ] }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            pages: { $push: "$pages" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            pages: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$pages",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kNO5NNyVc_M)

Comment: HELPED A LOT @mickl

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Basically we unwind the first array pages so that we get a huge list of pages. Then we group all xml requests arrays into one big array. And then we merge them into one array and return an object with a key requests contains the final array

```
    .aggregate([{
         $unwind: “$pages”,
    },
    {
         $group: {
              _id: null,
              xmlRequests: { $push: "$xmlRequests"}
          }
    },
    {
        $project: {
             _id: 0,
             requests: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$xmlRequests",
                    initialValue: [],
                     in: {
                         $concatArrays: [ "$$this", "$$value"]
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }])
```